# Signalr client method not firing when I use requireJs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, signalr

in my asp.net mvc web application  I am using angularjs  signalr and requirejs..

I created a angularjs service to setup signalr on the client, and i call this from the angularjs controller to send a message to signalr server,

the server calls back the client method and angularjs updates the ui.

This works when I have all my angularjs code and signalr client in a script tag in the razor page

but when I incorporated requirejs then the signalr server method is called when I send the message but the client function is never called from the server to send back to the client

MEANING THE  'acceptGreet' GREET EVENT OF THE PROXY IS NEVER TRIGGERED (please see code)
i have searched for a solution, I hope i am clear enough, here is my code and thanks

```
define(["app/js/modules/appModule"], function (app) {
var service = app.factory('feedService', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        proxy: null,
        initialize: function (acceptGreetCallback) {
            //Getting the connection object
            connection = $.hubConnection();

            //Creating proxy
            this.proxy = connection.createHubProxy('feeds');

            //Starting connection
            connection.start(function () {
                console.log('started..', this.proxy)

            });

            //Attaching a callback to handle acceptGreet client call
            this.proxy.on('acceptGreet', function (message) {

                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    acceptGreetCallback(message);
                });
            });
        },
        sendRequest: function (message) {
            //Invoking greetAll method defined in hub

            this.proxy.invoke('greetAll', message);
        }
    }
});
return service;})
```

// THE FOLLOWING CONTROLLER CONSUMES THE SERVICE

```
  define([app/js/services/feeds/feedService'], function () {

var controller = function ($scope, feedSssssexrvice) {
    $scope.text = "";
    $scope.message = [];
    $scope.greetAll = function () {
        feesService.sendRequest($scope.text);
    }

    updateGreetingMessage=function(text)
    {
        $scope.message.push(text);
    }
    feedService.initialize(updateGreetingMessage);

}
return controller;})
```

//REQUIREJS CONFIG

```
   require.config({
    baseUrl: "/Client/"
    , paths: {
        "jquery": "libs/jquery-1.10.2.min"

               , 'signalr': 'libs/signalr/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min'


    },
    shim: {
        "angular": {
            exports: "angular"
            , deps: ["anglarFileUploadShim"]
          }
            , 'signalr': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            }
    }
});
require(['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'signalr', 'app/feeds/js/bootstrap'], function ($) {

});
```

//signalr server

```
[HubName("feeds")]
    public class FeedHub:Hub
    {
        public void GreetAll(string text)
        {
            Clients.All.acceptGreet(text);
        }


    }
```

Comment: SOLVED- I HAD TO CALL THE connection.start() after wiring the client method